# Are there closed forms for $\Psi(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n^z}} $ for $z \in \Bbb N/\{1,2\} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

> Are there closed forms for $$ \Psi(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n^z}} $$

for $\Psi(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n^z}} $ for $z \in \Bbb N/\{1,2\}? $

I found closed forms for $\Psi(1)$ and $\Psi(2).$ I haven't been able to proceed for $\Psi(3)$ or larger integral values.

Comment: What was the result for $z=2$?  Did the solution involve the Theta Function?

Comment: yes it involved the theta function